# Regexp conversion from perl to C++

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

We have [following regexp](https://regex101.com/r/mI4vZ5/1) for parsing equations like `5x+10x^3-10x^2`:

`[+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*`

Following code in `c++`, taken from example and modified for task, leads to infinite loop:

```
std::regex words_regex("[+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*");
auto words_begin = 
            std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::string match_str = match.str(); 
    std::cout << match_str << '\n';
}
```

Also it's throws warnings on compile:

```
1.cpp:21:35: warning: unknown escape sequence '\d' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex words_regex("[+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*");
                                  ^~
1.cpp:21:43: warning: unknown escape sequence '\^' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex words_regex("[+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*");
                                          ^~
1.cpp:21:45: warning: unknown escape sequence '\d' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex words_regex("[+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*");
```

If we naively convert regexp to `[+-]?[d(x)]*[^d]*` - infinite loops leaves of course.

How correctly convert regexp for `c++`?

**UPD**: 
Clang version:

```
Mac:concurrent macbook$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `\d` is being attempted to be interpreted as an escape sequence, so you have to escape the backslash, as in `\\d`.

An alternative is to use a raw string literal, as in:

```
std::regex words_regex(R"([+-]?[\d(x)]*[\^\d]*)");
```

See it in action [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7345835846c6f1a3).

Comment: Looks like an answer, but it still fades in infinite loop in example taken from action :(

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying, can you be more specific? Can you perhaps provide the specific code and input that causes the infinite loop to occur? I provided a link to a comprehensive solution which shows that it works for the example equation input you provided.

Comment: it looks like compiler problem on my side. If I take code from http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7345835846c6f1a3 - it compiles but also leads to infinite loop locally. Added clang version to question..